# How to draw a forest plot showing variance between different studies for meta-analysis

Tags: r, plot, variance, r-forestplot

I have a dataframe consisting of 625 samples from 11 different studies and this dataframe consists of count values. Additionally, I have a metadata also consisting of all the informations related to those samples. Now, I want to draw a forest plot in R showing the variance between different studies but don't know how to do this.
Here is the dataframe of count values

[image]

and the meta_data is like this

[image]

I tried to extract mean and standard deviation of each study. This is the individual mean and sd for each study

```
Study    Mean      Sd             Sample size
1      1.345178   5.035716          87
2      3.069523   12.43596           6
3      1.328704   1.156703           8
4      2.151764   10.83554          40
5      1.166667   0.6389027          9
6      33.81678   318.2313          50
7      1.080769   0.4088965         26
8      1.453985   4.861426         102
9      6.418909   50.16277          28
10     2.307296   35.7949          260
11     3.722918   6.380527           9
```

How to use this information to draw forest plot in R?

Comment: When looking at differences in variance, the appropriate plot is a "funnel plot".

Comment: Could you please elaborate through an example that how can I create a funnel plot with the above given informations